# Tick label gets overwritten when figure is saved

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am messing around with drawing "traditional" intersecting axes:

```
x = range(-1, 2)
y = range(-1, 2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.5))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.5))
ax.plot(x, y)
```

This works OK:

[image]

I don't like the duplcate zeros, so I get rid of the one on the y-axis and move the x-axis one over:

```
fig.canvas.draw()  # Force the ticks to be computed now
next(tick for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
     if tick.get_loc() == 0.0).set_visible(False)
plt.setp(next(tick for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
              if tick.get_loc() == 0.0).label, ha='right', text='0  ')
```

This *almost* works:

[image]

The y-axis zero is removed, and the x-axis one is aligned properly-ish. However the label is not changed from `0.0` to `0` as expected.

I verified that before the call to `fig.savefig()`, the label is indeed correct. However, it gets reformatted when the figure is saved. How do I correctly change the label so that it reads `0` in the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would split the problem.

1. You want to have a custom text for the label at position `0`
2. You want to move the label.

#### Create custom text for a label at a certain position

An idea can be to subclass the `ScalarFormatter` and let it return a custom label for the zero position. This can either be an empty string or the number zero formatted in the way you desire.

```
from matplotlib import ticker as mticker
class CustomTicker(mticker.ScalarFormatter):
    def __init__(self, zero="0", **kwargs):
        self.zero=zero
        mticker.ScalarFormatter.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
        if x != 0:
            return mticker.ScalarFormatter.__call__(self, x, pos)
        else:
            return self.zero

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(CustomTicker(zero="0"))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(CustomTicker(zero=""))
```

The advantage of using a formatter here is understood as follows. The ticklabels (i.e. the `Text` instances on the canvas) do not have a fixed string set to them, until the figure is drawn. And this string may then change, after each subsequent draw, depending on the axis limits or changes to the figure size. Behind the scenes, a locator determines the locations of the ticks. The ticklabels are then positionned next to the ticks. A formatter then sets the string of the label, depending on the position. This is done by calling the formatter with the position `x` as argument. As example, the second ticklabel may initially be positionned at x=-10 and show the value `"-10"`. When changing the limits of the axes (e.g. by zooming) this very same label, may get placed at position x=-20. The call to the formatter then makes sure that its text is updated to show `"-20"` as well. `"-10"` is then instead shown by the third ticklabel. Wanting to keep track of those changes is cumbersome. Hence manipulating the formatter itself, allows to not having to care about those internals.

#### Move a single label

While many of the properties of the labels are set in a centralized manner, their actual transform is not. Hence one can translate a single label via a transform. Here we might choose to translate it in pixel space (i.e. *after* the main transform is performed). Because the individual labels may change their content when changing the limits (i.e. when zooming or panning), we might create a callback to change the transform of the one label at zero position, independent of the actual limits.
In the following we translate the `"0"` by `-10` pixels.

```
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans

basetrans = ax.get_xticklabels()[0].get_transform()
def movelabel(evt=None):
    trans = basetrans + mtrans.Affine2D().translate(-10,0)
    for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
        if tick.get_loc() == 0.0:
            tick.label.set_transform(trans)
        else:
            tick.label.set_transform(basetrans)

fig.canvas.draw()
movelabel()
ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', movelabel)
ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', movelabel)
```

#### Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker as mticker

x = range(-1, 2)
y = range(-1, 2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(0.1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(0.5))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(0.1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(0.5))

ax.plot(x, y)

from matplotlib import ticker as mticker
class CustomTicker(mticker.ScalarFormatter):
    def __init__(self, zero="0", **kwargs):
        self.zero=zero
        mticker.ScalarFormatter.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
        if x != 0:
            return mticker.ScalarFormatter.__call__(self, x, pos)
        else:
            return self.zero

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(CustomTicker(zero="0"))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(CustomTicker(zero=""))


import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans

basetrans = ax.get_xticklabels()[0].get_transform()
def movelabel(evt=None):
    trans = basetrans + mtrans.Affine2D().translate(-10,0)
    for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
        if tick.get_loc() == 0.0:
            tick.label.set_transform(trans)
        else:
            tick.label.set_transform(basetrans)

fig.canvas.draw()
movelabel()
ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', movelabel)
ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', movelabel)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm happy that you understood what I'm trying to achieve with the spacing.

Comment: I was really hoping to avoid custom formatters. Do you know the reasoning behind changing the label text when saving the figure?

Comment: I see what you mean and added some explanation to the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: My confusion was not so much about formatters and locators as the label's text property. I gather from your explanation that that property is completely dynamic and is never respected on its own, only used as a placeholder after each redraw. Will keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Also, went do you need to set the transform in the else case? Wouldn't leaving the existing one be sufficient?

Comment: That's exactly for the same reason. If you changed the transform for the third label, which initially shows the `"0"` but then its value is changed to `"10"`, you need to set the transform back to the `basetrans` for it not to be shifted as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

- Use your method to hide *either* x *or* y-ticklabels.
- Get the remaining/existing/displayed x or y-ticklabels as strings.
- Replace the `'0.0'` string by an integer `0`. I use `[1:-1]` because the output of `get_text()` in this case are strings surrounded by `$` as `$-1.0$`, `$0.0$`, `$1.0$` etc.
- Finally reset the x or y-ticklabels.

**Hiding `0.0` from the x-axis**

```
fig.canvas.draw()  # Force the ticks to be computed now
next(tick for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
     if tick.get_loc() == 0.0).set_visible(False)

labels = [item.get_text()[1:-1] for item in ax.get_yticklabels()]
new_labels = [ "%d" % int(float(l)) if l == '0.0' else l for l in labels]
ax.set_yticklabels(new_labels)
ax.set_title('Hiding the 0.0 from x-axis')
```

[image]

**Hiding `0.0` from the y-axis**

```
fig.canvas.draw()  # Force the ticks to be computed now
next(tick for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
     if tick.get_loc() == 0.0).set_visible(False)

labels = [item.get_text()[1:-1] for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
new_labels = [ "%d" % int(float(l)) if l == '0.0' else l for l in labels]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
ax.set_title('Hiding the 0.0 from y-axis')
```

[image]

Comment: This works because under the hood `set_yticklavels` sets `FixedFormatter` as the major formatter. It doesn't move the labels like I want, but +1 regardless.

Comment: Also, leaving $...$ is not a bad idea, it makes the labels more latexy looking